# How to change localhost to ec2 public dns

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have an ec2 instance on which i login as:

`ssh -L 5001:localhost:5000 sumit@<public DNS>`

I have an application (superset) which I run as:

```
2020-04-01 08:18:24,531:INFO:root:logging was configured successfully
2020-04-01 08:18:24,620:INFO:root:Configured event logger of type <class 'superset.utils.log.DBEventLogger'>
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
2020-04-01 08:18:25,600:INFO:werkzeug: * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Now when I open my browser and type, then it works:

`http://127.0.0.1:5001/`

[image]

I already have setup all http and https traffic:

[image]

Now when I change 127.0.0.1 to the aws public dns address it doesn't work. Please let me know what am I missing?

Comment: Why do you want to change `127.0.0.1` to the public DNS? Presumably, the application is not publicly accessible, which is why you are using Port Forwarding.

Comment: No i dont want.. the only thing that i require is to run the app from public dns (i.e. anywhere)

Comment: Okay, so you want the "Superset" application to be publicly accessible? See [Publish Superset dashboard online and remote login · Issue #3489 · apache/incubator-superset](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/issues/3489) and [Failure on access from remote browser · Issue #8336 · apache/incubator-superset](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/issues/8336).

Answer (score 0):

You method is using something call **Port Forwarding**.

This command:

```
ssh -L 5001:localhost:5000 sumit@<public DNS>
```

is saying: "Please SSH into the instance, and also *forward* port 5001 on this computer to the other computer, and ask it to send the traffic to `localhost:5000`."

Therefore, any traffic sent to port 5001 on your computer will be forwarded to port 5001 on the target computer. This is a good way of preventing other people from being able to access port 5000 on that computer, unless they are able to SSH into the instance (presumably using a private key).

Accessing `http://127.0.0.1:5001/` means it will go to port 5001 on *your* computer. It would be the same as going to `http://localhost:5001` on your own computer.

The flow is: `127.0.0.1:5001 -> via SSH connection -> localhost:5000 on other computer`

Changing it to `http://DNS-NAME:5001` will try to connect to port 5001 on the destination computer, which is not a port that is in use. You could try changing it to connect to `http://DNS-NAME:5000` (which is the port where the application seems to be running) and opening the Security Group to allow port 5000, but that would probably violate the security that somebody probably wanted to put in place.

Comment: yes, thats not the solution.. in fact dns name approach is not working altogether